# Erro de Rota Axios e React-Native

Tags: react, docker, axios

Fala galera, tudo bem? Bom, estou com um erro no axios e já fiz de tudo para resolver e não consegui. Então, deixa eu explicar um pouco.

Esse aqui é o meu método post no lado servidor. Qualquer alteração que fizer aqui, ao entrar no navegador(pela rota) e banco de dados é totalmente funcional.

```
app.post("/metas", (req, res) => {

    const { metas } = req.body;

    let SQL = "INSERT INTO listametas ( metas ) VALUES (?)";

    db.query(SQL, metas, (err, result) => {

        if (err) {

            console.log(err);
            return;

        } else {

            console.log('Inserção realizada com sucesso!');

            res.send('Inserção realizada com sucesso!')

        }

    });
    
});
}
```

Já no lado cliente, o meu endereço de IP está inserido e a rota também. Porém, ele não chega nem a chamar o método post no lado servidor. Esse é o meu código:

```
const submeterInformacao = (metas) => {
    axios.post("http://192.168.1.9:3001/metas", { metas: metas } );
};
```

Sempre o erro que é apresentado é o de exceder o tempo limite.
Esse erro:

```
WARN  Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 2):
[AxiosError: timeout exceeded]
```

Queria saber se alguém pode me auxiliar. Já fiz todos os procedimentos na porta 3001, e nada funciona. já baixei novamente todas as extensões necessárias. Enfim, qualquer informação a mais pode perguntar. Dese já, obrigado!

link da página completa do lado cliente: https://commie.io/#KLHjcuep
link da página completa do lado servidor: https://commie.io/#Tf6A1YKX